# Variable assignment and simultaneous check of the return code in conditional statements

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

What are the contras for writing bash scripts like in the example below?
Would you separate a variable assignment or a function call from the check of its return code? If so, why? What is wrong - if anything - with this kind of conditionals?

```
local return_code=0
if username=$(get_username "${user}") \  
   && is_from_earth "${user}"; then  
   echo "${username} is an earthling"
else  
   echo "ERROR: no name or not from the Earth"  
   return_code=1 
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong, per se, but in the interest of more accurate error messages, I'd probably write something like

```
local return_code=1
if ! username=$(get_username "$user"); then
    echo "ERROR: no such user '$user'" >&2
elif ! is_from_earth "$username"; then
    echo "ERROR: $username is not from Earth" >&2
else
    echo "$username is an earthing"
    return_code=0
fi
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. 
Some people say, one should never make an assignment and check for the return code at once, because it can cause difficulties during debugging; or that in other programming languages (like C) the compiler would complain / not allow this kind of assignments. That is why I am asking: in order to understand if it is really so bad to do that in bash and what damage it can really cause (I use this construct a lot in bash).

Comment: @Lina This is good advice in C because `if (x = foo())` and `if(x == foo())` are very similar and easily confused/typo'd. It does not apply to sh/bash because `if x=$(foo)` and `if [ "$x" = "$(foo)" ]` are very different and won't be accidentally swapped.

Comment: Shell is more similar to the newer idiom in Python involving the assignment expression, where you can now write something like `if (foo := bar()) is None: # use foo here`, where `if (foo = bar()) is None: ...` is a syntax error and you had to write `foo = bar(); if foo is None: ...`.